# Project solution structure

Tags: c++, visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

I'm planning a new project that I'll develop in C++. I need a good solution structure, for a quick project overview. My project is a tcp based server. This server is able to save files and text from client into a database or on the filesystem. The server can also send files and data from the database back to the client. My structure should look like:

```
Solution
- main.cpp
- DataAccess
--- Header
--- Source
- Business
--- Header
--- Source
- CrossCutting
--- Header
--- Source
- Server
--- Header
--- Source
--------------------------------
- External Dependencies
- Tests (Unit and Integration)
- Documentation
```

That's my idea. Here a little introduction for this folder structure:

DataAccess: Here is the connection between logic and data (database, io)

Business: Here is all the logic. Only the business has access to the data access layer

Server: This is my server layer. Client request will be processed there. Only the server layer has access to the business layer.

CrossCutting: This layer is a little bit specieal. Here are functions, classes, entites, etc., which will be needed in several layers.

I think the other folders should be clear. If not, let me know them.
What do you think about this solution structure? Is this a good start or should I need rework?

Comment: This question invites opinions as answers, and the answers provided are dated (they would not apply to similar questions). Voted to close.

Comment: I'm agree with you. But the most good skilled dev's can say, that this is crap or not.

Comment: Ok, I will add an answer (if people don't close the question before I finish writing it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What do you think about this solution structure? Is this a good start or should I need rework?

It's a good start; it could use some rework :)

This is fine if you are thinking of a single project. Ideally you should split this into multiple projects (as separate lib/dll projects) and have a main project that contains your main.cpp and launches the application/server/service.

Advantages of splitting into multiple projects:

- compartmentalization of dependencies, per project
- improved testability of the code
- separation of responsibilities is enforced (more than with a single project) and formalization of internal protocols is better (at least in theory - you will have to take care to formalize your internal protocols)

I would consider the following changes:

root // project root, source control root, etc

- ExternalDependencies
- Doc
- Src

  - solution file [linking to the four projects below and Tests]
  - Tests

    - containing test projects in here [each in it's own directory]
      -
  - Application [dir]

    - main.cpp
    - main project file (.vcxproj I think)
  - DataAccess

    - headers and sources, not split into separate directories (because this is the visual studio default and it will decrease mistakes caused by default settings in visual studio)
    - project file
  - Business [same structure as DataAccess]
    ...

I would also define some common property pages near the solution file, where I would specify common build and temporary build directories, then inherit these property pages accross the projects; This would centralize build artifacts and  binaries, and ease the editing of common settings.

Note: I am currently working on a relatively large project (~180 projects in the solution), using this structure.

Comment: I've one question. Should be each layer a separate library/project?

Comment: @MarcelHoffmann, yes. They should be different visual studio projects, added to the same solution file.